# How to apply same content to multiple html pages

Tags: html

I'm new to html and was wondering if there is a way to apply the same content to many html files at once.

For example, if I have many pages, but all those pages have an identical navigation side panel  that contains links to all the other pages. Is there any way to change the contents of this side panel without changing it for each individual page?
i.e. is there a feature that allows me to make this navigation panel in a separate file, then tell all my pages to include this navigation file?

I know a css file can control the format of many html pages - is there an analogy to this that can control the content of many html pages?

Comment: This is called a *[Content Management System (CMS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system)*. You could also use a publishing platform like [WordPress](http://wordpress.org).

Comment: (i)frames? ;) No really don't use it :)

Comment: @PeeHaa - You're going to have to be more specific.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I don't get what a CMS has to do with 'include' like features.

Comment: @PeeHaa - It's a method of managing content, of which paged content is one type. The simpler form would be a publishing platform like WordPress.

Comment: @JaredFarrish sorry I still don't get what does have to do with includes :P Might be just me though

Comment: @PeeHaa - http://drupal.org/project/pages A page is a type of content, I don't know how else to explain it. Admittedly, a full-blown CMS is probably not necessary, but it's a common approach.

Comment: @JaredFarrish actually a common approach is `server side includes` which a CMS system may implement

Comment: Check this SO question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712338/make-header-and-footer-files-to-be-included-in-multiple-html-pages

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use PHP to do that. Write the HTML code in PHP file, then add include statement in your HTML. This saves you from having to write same code again and again specially for navigation, etc.

[PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) explains it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why not link to the actual [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)?

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look at that link :)

Comment: @JaredFarrish I didn't link to php manual as xiaodii said he is new to HTML and the php manual doesn't explain the HTML part of it.

Comment: As the link in the answer points out, readfile() is better than include when there is no PHP in the file being imported.  readfile() just passes the content through to the output buffer.  include inserts the content, then parses it as part of the executing script.

Answer (score 4):

You can write the common content in javascript file and include it in your html pages using [script tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp):

```
<script src="YOUR_FILE.js"></script>
```

You can use an online HTML to Javascript converter like [this one](http://www.accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/html-javascript-convertor/) to generate you javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

Server-side includes or server-side programming languages (like PHP, for example), are often used to do that. All pages just include a shared common file, which contains the common content.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include(file with extension);

?>
```

You'd have to change your file extension that runs this code to DOT php