# Using a content box in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

Can somebody help me please. I operate the website www.springfield-pyc.co.uk

On the right there are some content boxes, Useful links, news, and adverts. I wonders if there was a way that i can change the content of these boxes once and have it copied over to every other page. 
For example, what ever is in the 'News' box on /index will then be displayed in the 'News' box in /about

Hope that makes sense, thanks for any help!

Comment: You could take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548738/how-to-apply-same-content-to-multiple-html-pages

Comment: Yes there is but Stackoverflow is not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this **news , useful links , advert** code in **different files...**

And using php you can call any file where you want on any page (that way will be easy for you)

for example , for advertisement use advert.html  , for news use news.html  like that...

using Php ... call above file

```
<pre>

<?php
include('file_name with extension');
?>
</pre>
```